# Update TradingView Hotlist Widget onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tradingview-api

Below is my component for firing up the widget, I would like to change the exchange when a new value is selected from the select tag. The onChange changes the state value, however the widget doesn't change the values it's looking at. Any ideas how to make it work?

```
import React from "react"; 

export default  class StockGainer extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this._ref = React.createRef();
        this.state = { 
        exchange:
         "TSX" 
        }
    }
 componentDidMount() {
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = 'https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-hotlists.js' 
        script.async = true;
        this._ref.current.appendChild(script);
        script.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(
            {
                  "colorTheme": "dark",
                  "dateRange": "12M",
                  "exchange": `${this.state.exchange}`,
                  "showChart": true,
                  "locale": "en"
                })
    }
   


    render() {

        const Changeexchange = (e) => { 

            this.setState({exchange: e.target.value})
        }  

        const SelectBox = () => (
            <div class="select-div">
            <select className="exchange" value={this.state.exchange} name="pagination" onChange={Changeexchange}>
              <option value="US"> USA (US Exchanges)</option>
              <option value="NASDAQ"> USA (NASDAQ)</option>
              <option value="NYSE"> USA (NYSE)</option>
              <option value="AMEX"> USA (NYSE ARCA)</option>
              <option value="OTC"> USA (OTC)  </option>
            </select>
            </div>
        )

        return(
          
        <div class="tradingview-widget-container" ref={this._ref}>
            <div style={{position:"absolute", top: "0px", left:"318px"}}>{SelectBox()}</div> 
         <div class="tradingview-widget-container__widget"> </div>
          {console.log(this.state.exchange)}
        </div>
        );
    }
   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `id` to your element (iframe in this case) and then on `select` onChange call you can delete the previous iframe based on the stored element id and then create a fresh element.

[Working Example With Comments](https://codesandbox.io/s/stocktrading-tradingview-r39hl)

Code -

```
Changeexchange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ exchange: e.target.value });

    // Remove the existing DOM elem
    const elem = document.getElementById(this.currentDOMId);
    elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);

    // Create a new elem with updated values
    // so that updated iframe will load
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.id = `dom-exchng-id-${this.state.exchange}`;
    this.currentDOMId = `dom-exchng-id-${this.state.exchange}`;
    script.src =
      "https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-hotlists.js";
    script.async = true;
    this._ref.current.appendChild(script);
    script.innerHTML = JSON.stringify({
      colorTheme: "dark",
      dateRange: "12M",
      exchange: e.target.value,
      showChart: true,
      locale: "en"
    });
  };
```

Fyi, I have formatted your code a bit, as you are referring `className` as `class` in your code.

Comment: Your Awesome man!! Gonna have to look in the code to learn exactly how you did it! Really appreciate it

Comment: @Ibra : Glad it helped you !!

Answer (score 0):

Changing the exhange in the state isn't enough, you need to create the whole script tag again if you want update the widget. You can create function "updateWidget" and call it in componentDidMount and on the changeExhange function.

I also created new div for the widget **tradingView** and we need to clear it with innerHTML='' every time we update the widget. Otherwise it creates multiple widgets every time we change exhange.

```
import React from "react"; 

export default  class StockGainer extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this._ref = React.createRef();
      this.state = { 
      exchange:
       "TSX" 
      }
  }
componentDidMount() {
    this.updateWidget()
  }
 
  updateWidget(){
      this._ref.current.innerHTML=''
      const script = document.createElement('script');
      script.src = 'https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-hotlists.js' 
      script.async = true;
      this._ref.current.appendChild(script);
      script.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(
          {
                "colorTheme": "dark",
                "dateRange": "12M",
                "exchange": `${this.state.exchange}`,
                "showChart": true,
                "locale": "en"
              })
  }

  render() {

      const Changeexchange = (e) => { 

          this.setState({exchange: e.target.value})
          this.updateWidget()

      }  

      const SelectBox = () => (
          <div class="select-div">
          <select className="exchange" value={this.state.exchange} name="pagination" onChange={Changeexchange}>
            <option value="US"> USA (US Exchanges)</option>
            <option value="NASDAQ"> USA (NASDAQ)</option>
            <option value="NYSE"> USA (NYSE)</option>
            <option value="AMEX"> USA (NYSE ARCA)</option>
            <option value="OTC"> USA (OTC)  </option>
          </select>
          </div>
      )

      return(
        
      <div class="tradingview-widget-container" >
          <div style={{position:"absolute", top: "0px", left:"318px"}}>{SelectBox()}</div> 
          <div ref={this._ref} id='tradingView'></div>
       <div class="tradingview-widget-container__widget"> </div>
        {console.log(this.state.exchange)}
      </div>
      );
  }
 
}
```

Comment: This also looks like an amazing answer! I appreciate your time and effort! I will look on both answers and decide the reward goes to who. Thank You